# Why does `isValidSignature` (EIP-1271) need to be a view function?

Tags: eip-1271

In all the documentation that I have read about EIP1271, every time the `isValidSignature` function is implemented it is a view function. Even in the OpenZeppelin IERC1271 interface they use view. Is it considered a secure/ compliant implementation if I were to create my own IERC1271 interface which does potential modify the contract state?

`function isValidSignature(bytes32 hash, bytes memory signature) external returns (bytes4 magicValue);`

Why was the EIP originally written with the intent to only have this function be `view`?